# embed jquery themes in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a DLL and I'm trying to wrap the jquery progress bar inside an asp.net server control with the jquery lightness theme.
 I was able to embed the jquery into the control but the css isn't showing up. Do I have to embed each image into the assembly? Here's what I have right now

```
[assembly: WebResource("MyNamespace.jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css", "text/css")]
[assembly: WebResource("MyNamespace.jquery-1.5.1.min.js", "text/javascript")]
[assembly: WebResource("MyNamespace.jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js", "text/javascript")]
```

The images are in a folder called /images/ in the root of the DLL. the jquery is referencing the images like this.

```
.ui-state-error .ui-icon, .ui-state-error-text .ui-icon {background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ffd27a_256x240.png); }
```

But none of the images show up. I feel like there should be an easier way then having to add a web resource for each image. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does not search the image in the dll-directory but in the subdirectory of the page using your control. you have to see the paths as seen by a browser and not as seen by the local dll.

so a page `http://localhost/yourpage.aspx` which uses the progressbar would search the images in `http://localhost/images/...`

i hope you understand what i mean

adding a web resource for each image wouldn't solve the problem (if I see it right)